# Category deep function

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

How to get category deep with space padding on this function. At the moment i have select box with all categories have the same level.

```
<?php
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'my_custom_metabox');
function my_custom_metabox() {
    add_meta_box('custom-taxonomy-dropdown','Brands','taxonomy_dropdowns_box','post','side','high');
}

function taxonomy_dropdowns_box( $post ) {
    global $brand_taxonomy, $taxonomy_name;
    wp_nonce_field('custom-dropdown', 'dropdown-nonce');
    $terms = get_terms( $brand_taxonomy, 'hide_empty=1&hierarchical=1;');
    if ( is_a( $terms, 'WP_Error' ) ) {
        $terms = array();
    }

    $object_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $brand_taxonomy, array('fields'=>'ids'));
    if ( is_a( $object_terms, 'WP_Error' ) ) {
        $object_terms = array();
    }

    // you can move the below java script to admin_head
    ?>

    <?php


    wp_dropdown_categories('show_option_none=Select category&show_count=1&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=ad_cat');



    echo "Brand:";
    echo "<select id='custombrandoptions' name='custombrands[]'>";
    echo "<option value='0'>None</option>";
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

        if ( in_array($term->term_id, $object_terms) ) {
            $parent_id = $term->term_id;
            echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}' selected='selected'>{$term->name}</option>";
        } else {
            echo "<option value='{$term->term_id}'>{$term->name}</option>";
        }

    }
    echo "</select><br />";



    echo '<input type="text" value="'.$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cat_include', true).'" />';

}
```

source: http://paste.php.lv/dc485b1e6f37f09f916fccc6ae70ed2f?lang=php

Comment: Are you asking how to create a select/option menu that has nested categories?

Comment: I asking, how to fix category sub levels padding on this function, from existing functions data. This function is part of advaced wordpress, meta box with drop down box and custom taxanomies inside on select list.

Comment: Here is fix:


wp_dropdown_categories('show_count=1&hierarchical=1&taxonomy=ad_cat&selected='.$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cat_include', true).'');

Return on selected argument meta box info.

Comment: Here is full moded version of this plugin. Mod make wp_drop_down categories with sublevels and paddings. Mod fix update and save functions.

Here is full moded functions code.

http://paste.php.lv/dc8786ed7b99038807c7f9741b30794a?lang=php

For output and custom query use: <?php $str = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'cat_include', true) ?>

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below. You can then select that answer as "the answer" which will mark your question as solved which will help to make this site work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where your problem is located but maybe you are looking fpr `str_repeat` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php ..

so you might use these way:

```
echo '<option value="" ..>'.str_repeat(' ',$currentLevel+1).'</option>';
```

(I do not understand how you get the deep of level.. perhaps it is a good idea to iterate recusrivly through the hierarchy..)